# FabricJS hasControls Border radius customiztion

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I would like to make the hasControls border radius match the object that is being selected so I tried adding `rx` and `ry` to rect but it doesn't seem to be impacting the hasControls object.

```js
var group = new fabric.Group([item, text], < any > {
  left: params.x,
  top: params.y,
  transparentCorners: false,
  lockRotation: true,
  hasRotatingPoint: false,
  borderColor: "yellow",
  cornerColor: "yellow",

  borderScaleFactor: .4,
  rx: 4,
  ry: 4
});
```

Answer (score 0):

no, it does not impact because the controls in fabricjs are rendered as simple rects.

if you want to add this feature to fabric you have to ovveride the renderControl method.copying the render logic from the rect class.